# KeyError: 8 in python dataframe when trying to access the values of dataframe column by index

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to classify the email as spam and non spam. This is the [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/chandramoulinaidu/spam-classification-for-basic-nlp).

Following is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import string
punct = string.punctuation
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('stopwords')
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopWords = stopwords.words('english')
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
nltk.download('wordnet')
wordnet_lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer


data = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/NLP/Spam Email .csv')


remove_tags = re.compile('<.*?>|&([a-z0-9]+|#[0-9]{1,6}|#x[0-9a-f]{1,6});')

def text_pre_processing(data):
  corpus = []
  for i in range(len(data['MESSAGE'])):
    print(i)
    token = data['MESSAGE'][i].replace('\n',' ')
    token = token.replace('\t',' ')
    token = token.replace('©',' ')
    token = token.replace('/b',' ')
    token = re.sub('(https?:\/\/)([\w]+.)*',' ',token) # to remove url
    token = re.sub('(www.)([\w]+.)*',' ',token)
    token = re.sub(remove_tags, ' ', token)#remove html tags
    token = "".join([word for word in token if word not in punct])
    #token = re.sub(' {2,}','',token)
    token = re.sub('([\d])*','',token) #remove numbers
    token = token.lower()
    token = word_tokenize(token)
    token = " ".join([wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in token if not word in set(stopWords)])
    corpus.append(token)
  
  return corpus

text_transformer = FunctionTransformer(text_pre_processing)

pipeline_rfc = Pipeline([
                         ('pre-processing', text_transformer), 
                         ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
                        ('Random Forest Classifier',RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 400,random_state = 0))
                        ]
                       )

X = data.iloc[:,1:2]
y = data.iloc[:,0:1]

xtrain,xtest,ytrain,ytest = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

pipeline_rfc.fit(xtrain,ytrain)
```

I am able to access data['MESSAGE'][8] outside the function text_pre_processing(data) but inside the function it shows KeyError:8.

This is the error I am getting.

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897             try:
-> 2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()
```

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Try this: `print(data['MESSAGE'])` and see what you get.

Comment: @bichanna it works fine.

Comment: What does it print?

Comment: 0       Dear Homeowner,\n\n \n\nInterest Rates are at ...
1       ATTENTION: This is a MUST for ALL Computer Use...
2       This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n...
3       IMPORTANT INFORMATION:\n\n\n\nThe new domain n...
4       This is the bottom line.  If you can GIVE AWAY...
                              ...                        
5793    On Mon, 2002-07-22 at 06:50, che wrote:\n\n\n\...
5794    Once upon a time, Manfred wrote :\n\n\n\n> I w...
5795    If you run Pick, and then use the "New FTOC" b...
Name: MESSAGE, Length: 5796, dtype: object

Comment: Could you please put that code in the question and format it? It's very hard to read.

Comment: @bichanna I have edited the question and posted an image of it.